# Build Succeeded but No Simulator being displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an app in iPhone,before making few changes the Simulator was working fine.After implementing the changes,when I have built the app but when I am building it,it says build succeeded but the iPhone as Simulator is not visible. Any hints ?

Console Output

```
2012-11-08 12:06:08.089 MyApp[743:f803] IT IS  COMING HERE
2012-11-08 12:06:08.093 MyApp[743:f803] IT IS  COMING HERE 1
2012-11-08 12:06:08.094 MyApp[743:f803] IT IS  COMING HERE 2
(lldb) 


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"IT IS  COMING HERE");
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    NSLog(@"IT IS  COMING HERE 1");
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"IT IS  COMING HERE 2");
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"IT IS  GOING FROM HERE");
    return YES;
```

Comment: That might be because it's not an emulator you have to expect but a simulator.

Comment: Maybe you got a slow mac hohoho. Put a `NSLog` in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Does it ever get there?

Comment: nothing much . just reset simulator

Comment: Reseting Xcode and Simulator did not work for me. I realised I had wrong schema selected. Schema can be chosen from the drop down in the Xcode's  top left corner - right next to available Simulators list drop down. Issue FIXED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue before, I solved it by the following methods:

Just **quit the simulator** and run the project again.
If it is not working then **quit the xcode** along with simulator and run the project again, it'll surely solve the issue.

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem

Comment: Much better answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800229/xcode-can-build-a-project-but-cant-run-it-on-simulator

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the simulator does not launch the app or gets a complete black screen even though x-code shows that build has succeeded. The best thing to do, as everyone pointed out, quit X-code and reset the simulator. Relaunch the app, and things should work fine.