# Program won't run in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm building an application in Xcode and the application won't run (the run button is greyed out). I made a copy of the initial program and began to work on the copied version to add some features.  Now the copied program won't run. Also, I can't selected if I want the program to run in the iPhone simulator or the iPad simulator. The only option is the 64 bit macbook. Any ideas as to why? Maybe because both program have the same executable file? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GO to target & check that You select right name of your App that you want to run like below

image:

[image]

And select right App name like below image:

[image]

Comment: The problem was I made a copy of the program and changed the name of the program to not get confused. It wouldn't run because the name of the program was different. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your scheme lacks a runnable configuration.

Take a look at [Xcode can build a project but can't run it on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800229/xcode-4-can-build-a-project-but-cant-run-it-on-simulator)